# Closing main form doesn't finish process in Windows 7

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-7

I have an MDI form as the app start object.

I don't think is related, but in the Form closing event, I check for some condition, and if it's true, I ask for confirmation before closing:

```
Private Sub FormBackground_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If (e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing) Then
        If (conditionIsMet) Then
            Dim res As DialogResult
            res = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If (res <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) Then
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So long, everything works fine in my development machine, which runs windows XP.

However, when deploying the application in a windows 7 machine, the message box works correctly, showing itself whenever it should, but after the form is closed the application keeps running in the background. This happens whether the form closes directly or asks the user first.

I have (hopefully) fixed it putting an End instruction in the FormBackground.FormClosed event, but it doesn't feel good. As a workaround it's OK for now but I'd like to find the cause of the problem.

Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was caused by a third party COM library.
The only working solution I could find:

```
Private Sub MDIParentForm_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If (e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing) Then
        If (Not CanClose()) Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
    If (Not e.Cancel) Then
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't like it, but it works when End doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

this has been discussed a lot lately, is it possible you have started some threads in your application and you did not set them as Background threads?

Comment: My threads ought to be short lived (a few seconds at most), so I declare myself guilty :) but don't think this is causing the problem. Anyway, should this **always** cause problems in win7 and **never** in XP?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely do not have all the forms of the application closed. Try this code

```
For Each frm as Form in My.Application.OpenForms
    frm.Close
Next
```

It will close every form in your application.

Comment: Alex Essilfie: Right, I'm not closing my forms, as I thought that being MDI, closing the parent would take care of the childs (and seems so in XP). I'll try this right now, however, why the difference between OSes?

Comment: Most of the time, .NET applications default to close when the last open form closes therefore your app won't close till the last form closes. If your application is a true MDI (as in all other forms are children of the main MDI form) then closing the main form should exit the app. If this is not the case then you'll always have to manually close every open form.

Comment: It's a true MDI app. However, this doesn't work, neither does the End instruction. It hangs forever and shows the "Application hung" dialog... I'll try to gather some info and update the question. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. Call it from your mdi formclosing
perhaps the error handler will pic something up.

```
Private Sub CloseAllDataforms()
    Dim frm As Form
    ' Unload all the child forms, if any.  
    Try
        For Each frm In Me.MdiChildren
            If Not frm.Name = "MDI_Main" Then
                If frm.IsMdiChild = True Then
                    frm.Close()
                    frm.Dispose()
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch eX As Exception
        Debug.Print(eX.Message.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```